# Was the conception of Angel's baby ever explained?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer, angel

Watching Angel, I have become curious if the mysterious conception of his child, Connor was ever explained (other than it being fortold, obviously)?

[image]

Comment: fortold -> foretold

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The end of season 4 explained it...Jasmine claimed to have arranged it.  In order to enter into the world she needed a body fathered by someone like Connor.  So she arranged for his conception, then manipulated Cordelia into ascending, then took over her body when she returned, then seduced Connor, and Jasmine then inhabited their baby.

I don't believe any other explanation was given in the series.

It was ...not the most convincing plotting the series ever did.

Comment: Did she arrange it or just take advantage of it? If I recall, there were a variety of cults and baddies trying to get hold of the boy.

Comment: I don't have the texts here, but I'm pretty sure she takes credit for arranging it.  I suppose that could be superseded by the comics, but I don't know what's in them.

Comment: I recall she takes credit for it, but she's not exactly a reliable witness

Comment: @Richard: I agree. It's also debatable how much influence she actually has on Earth until she is 'born.' She had to act through her agent, Kit, and unlike Glorificus, doesn't seem to have had any earthbound worshippers before she arrives. It seems like causing Angel and Darla to conceive a child is beyond her capabilities until she's present on Earth.

Comment: It'd be great if you could add a quote from her.

Comment: Her agent is Skip, and Skip makes Cordelia a demon, then a Higher Power, so obviously he has a lot of power.

Answer (score 11):

There are a number of theories, even in-universe, as no explanation was ever fully revealed.

However, a prominent and likely one is that Angel won it in [The Trial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trial_(Angel)).

Let's back up, though.

In the episode, [Epiphany](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Epiphany), Angel and Vampire-Darla have sex, in a plot to turn Angel back into Angelus with a moment of pure happiness.. (Un)fortunately, Angel doesn't love Darla, and remains as Angel.

Later, when Darla is dying, Angel undergoes a series of trials in order to save Darla's life. Even though Angel is successful at completing the trials, he is told that since Darla's life was already supernaturally saved, nothing more can be done for her.

While never explicitly stated, it is theorized that in lieu of saving Darla's life, a new one was granted - resulting in Darla's pregnancy.

Comment: A great answer and very well explained.

Comment: @phantom42: I was sure Drusilla had turned Darla back into a vampire by that point. Wesley explicitly states - "It's because they're both vampires, if that makes sense" - at one point, which implies that he's figured out part of how it happened, but that's as far as he can get.

Comment: @JamesSheridan Crap. You're right. The whole repeated Darla/Angel re/de-vamping gets confusing. Fixing it, thanks.